# Probability distribution function of an individual value $X$

Tags: probability

A binomial random variable $X$ has probability distribution function ${P(x)=(\frac85)(\frac{3}{4})^x(\frac14)^{3−x}}$ where $x = 0, 1, 2, 3$ and $k$ is a constant. Find ${P(X \ge 1)}$. I tried inputting $0$ as $x$ into the equation and subtracting one from it: $.975$. The answer is $.984$. Any suggestions on how to get to this answer will be greatly appreciated!

The original equation looked like ${P(x)=(k)(\frac{3}{4})^x(\frac14)^{3−x}}$ where k was solved in a previous problem to be the fraction and constant $\frac85$

Comment: $k$ is a constant? $C$ is also a constant?

Comment: In general however, a binomial random variable has probability distribution function $P(x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$. Given that $1/4=1-3/4$, I would strongly suspect that $p=3/4$ and $n=3$, $x=0,1,2,3$. I'm sure you must have some mix-up there. Also, if solved in this way, the solution $0.984$ results for $P(X\ge 1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on a wrong trip. The probabiliy distribution function should be $P(X=k)= {3 \choose k} \cdot \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) ^k \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) ^{3-k}$.

So the calculation for $P(X \geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1- {3 \choose 0} \cdot \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) ^0 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) ^{3-0}$

greetings,

calculus

Edit: This is the only way I got the result. Maybe at the assumptions there has been a change made.

Comment: I'm sure your solution is correct. He says it's a binomial distribution, so only what you have makes sense.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit to try to clarify my ambiguousness

Comment: @stumped In this case I do aggree with you and user1443°°.

Answer (score 0):

**X** can take values 0,1,2,3. 
Now, P(X>=1)=P(X=1,2,3)..
Again, summing over the given values of x=0,1,2,3,we must get 1.
P(X>=1)=1-P(X=0)=1-((8/5)*(1/64))=1-(1/40)=39/40=0.975..
what you have got,is sure correct.